# Reading dynamically from Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a sort of Excel made with that heading : https://hostr.co/w1c9EBIoxQQ8
I would like, if a column its added for a special case, that my code in `VB.NET`  can keep reading the Excel ( and the rows under the correct column ) dynamically considering the correct columns.
At the moment I have a an `Enum Xls` where I have enumerate all the columns with the relative values like that :

```
numcolumns = 158
col3_periodo = 1
col3_mese = 2
col3_tipologia = 3
col3_tipoRelazione = 4
col3_anagraficaFornitorePagante = 5
col3_anagraficaFornitore = 6
col3_vanFornitore = 7
...etc
```

And so its not dynamically at all.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You will ultimately have to store some piece of information somewhere to connect the two.  Where you store it and how you maintain it is all about what makes sense for a given application.  If all of the columns have a unique header, you can use `Match` to find the column that corresponds to given text  (`Match` is an Excel function, check out [`WorksheetFunction`](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/171780-excel-worksheet-function/).  That requires you to store column header details in your VB.NET though.

Comment: Also if you want more specific information, please post the relevant details in that Excel file to your question.  Your question is fairly vague as it stands (although I can roughly see what you're trying to do).  I (and probably others) do not want to open a random Excel file off the internet.